# Spring AOP intercept wrong generic method

Tags: java, spring-aop

I am trying to intercept a method but I think that Spring AOP give me the wrong jointpoint. See the example below:

```
public interface IMyDummyComponent <K>{
    public String getValue(final K key);
}
```

I have a class that implements this interfacce.

```
public class MyDummyComponent implements IMyDummyComponent<String>{

    @Override
    @Logging
    public String getValue(String key) {
        LOG.info("begin getValue()");
        return "value";
    }
}
```

Now here is my Spring AOP aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class LogginAspect {
    private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogginAspect.class);


    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.package.annotation.Logging)")
    public void loggingAnnotationPointcut() {
    }

    @Around("loggingAnnotationPointcut()")
    public Object methodsAnnotatedWithLogging(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        LOG.info("begin methodsAnnotatedWithLogging()");
        Object result = null;

        try {
            LOG.debug("begin interpected method=" + joinPoint.getSignature());
            result = joinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            LOG.debug("end interpected method=" + joinPoint.getSignature());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `joinPoint.getSignature()` return "`public String getValue(Object key)`" instead of "`public String getValue(String key)`". Is this a spring AOP bug ? I need to know the real signature of my joinpoint (`getValue(String key)`). Is there a form to get this using aspect? If you use reflection you can get this method by in my point of view this annotacion should get this. Thanks.

Comment: "The problem is that the joinPoint.getSignature() return "public String getValue(Object key)" instead of".... what does it mean? It should returns the object Signature....

Comment: Sorry I see... you mean the output... Uhm at least for Boolean in a method I've written it's returning the actual Boolean... I guess you have multiple implementations and a * as return... Can you share your exact pointcut?